# Number of parameters in NN

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

**Problem**

There is a problem with the classification of the alphabet having $X$ symbols. The pictures containing the letters are converted to a vector having size $s_1$. A neural network is with 1 hidden layer with a hidden size of $s_2$, ReLU activation function after the hidden layer and biases in all the layers are applied.

What is the number of parameters?
Is the use of another activation function after the output layer needed?

**My attempt**

a. I think the number of parameters is $bias + weights = s_2 + X + [s_1\cdot s_2 + s_2 \cdot X ]$. But I don't consider the fact the activation function is ReLU.

b. I guess another function is not required as we can specify a threshold for ReLU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each node is $relu(WX + b)$ then we will have $(s1 +1)s2$
and for the output layer we will have $(s2 + 1) * X$
so total of:

$(s1 +1)s2$ + $(s2 +1) * X$

Is the use of another activation function after the output layer needed? - Yes, you need a softmax for the output in order to have a normalized probability(i.e. they will all sum up to 1)

Comment: Shouldn't we add X as well? According to this answer, we add also bias from output layer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3335072/how-many-parameters-does-the-neural-network-have/3335078

Comment: @Denezio - right. edited to account for the bias of the output layer.